# Dynamic defaultValue for Pageable default-size in openapi for a spring boot 3 webflux controller

Tags: spring-data, spring-webflux, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using a Pageable as a method parameter in a spring webflux controller.
I wanted to be able to override the default page size and the max size of the Pageable do a configurable property. I can do this using setters on the ReactivePageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver, as setting global properties does not work for pageable in a webflux app, only in a webmvc one.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

// a ConfigurationProperties class that holds the customisable values
  private final PageableProperties pageableProperties;

  @Override
  public void configureArgumentResolvers(final ArgumentResolverConfigurer configurer) {
    final var resolver = new ReactivePageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
    resolver.setMaxPageSize(pageableProperties.getMaxPageSize());
  resolver.setFallbackPageable(Pageable.ofSize(pageableProperties.getDefaultPageSize()));
    configurer.addCustomResolver(resolver);
  }


}
```

However openapi still displays the default value as 20, even if this is not the case. I am using the annotation @ParameterObject for OpenAPI to create the various sections for the pageable properties.

```
public Mono<String> doSomething(@ParameterObject final Pageable ageable)
{
//some logic
}
```

[image]
If I add the @PageableDefault(size = 100) after the @ParameterObject, I can override the defaut page size that appears in the openapi docs, but this requires a constant rather than coming from a configurable property.

If I add @PageableDefault without the size attribute, then it defaults to 10.

Is there any way to either get openapi to be able to use a dynamic value for the default page size, or to remove the default value entirely from the openapi docs?